# Theme a link with l - redirect to translated version

Tags: navigation, i18n-l10n, redirection

I'd like to insert a link in my node templates that displays when viewing nodes of a particular type (news). That link should lead to the news archive (node/26). Node 26 is a normal drupal page made in swedish (with a menu item and so on). On that page a block is displayed with a viewed list of news items.

There is a translated version of node/26 - translated with normal multi language modules.

What I'd lite for the system is to redirect from node/26 to the english translated version (node/27) if the current users language is english.

I have the module Translation Redirect activated - but it does not redirect.

If a redirect can't be achieved - is there any way that the link function can create the link depending on what the current language is (preferably without if-cases for each language).

Version is Drupal 7.

Thank you very much for any replies!

Comment: Try `Internationalization` module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing it this way:

```
$nodepath = "node/26";
$languagepaths = translation_path_get_translations($nodepath);
$currentlanguage = i18n_language()->language;
$path = $languagepaths[$currentlanguage];

if (preg_match('/^node/',$path)) {
    $path = "". drupal_get_path_alias($path, $currentlanguage);
} else {
   $path = $nodepath;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
global $language;
$link = url('node/26',array('language' => $language));
?>
<a href="<?php print $link?>">My Page</a>
```

credit to mojzis solution.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

according to the [docs](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7) it should be enough to do something like this :

```
global $language;
$link = l('GO THERE','node/26',array('language' => $language));
```